# Color shemes in webstorm 7 - how to install?

Tags: webstorm

How to install color scheme in webstorm 7 on windows? 
There are no any folder named webide10 in my user's folder.

Theme that I want to install is here https://github.com/negativefix/zenburn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For WEbStorm7 the Zenburn.xml  has to be placed into ~.WebStorm7\config\colors\ folder (where ~ is your home folder, like `'C:\Users\my.name\.WebStorm7\config\colors\Zenburn.xml'`

Answer (score 37):

Select «File» → «Import Setting» from the main menu and follow the instructions. 
After the IDE restarted go to the Preferences, expand «Editor» → «Colors and fonts» tab and choose the installed theme.

Comment: This answer is clearly more widely applicable and generic, which is desirable in this case, for this particular question.

Comment: This method did not work for me when trying to install the Monokai Bright theme from the following URL, but @lena's answer did. http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/theme/monokai-bright

Comment: @soulBit in order for this method to work, you need to import a `.jar` file, xml files won't work this way.